# ¿Cómo le puedo pasar una fila de una matriz a una función?

Tags: c++, matrices

Estoy haciendo un programa que lee una operacion en binario y 2 numeros en binario de hasta 8bytes
si la operacion es 0 entonces es > . Me hice una matriz con todas las operaciones llamada operaciones
operaciones[0] = 0
entonces quiero checkearlo con la operacion que me mando el usuario . . .

```
char operacion[8];
        char numeroA[8];
        char numeroB[8];
        char operaciones[5][8] = {{'0','\0'},{'1','\0'},{'1','0','\0'},{'1','1','\0'},{'1','0','0','\0'}};
        cin >> operacion >> numeroA >> numeroB;
        if(esIgual(operacion,operaciones[0]) ){
           cout<<"greater than";
           }
    }
    return 0;

}
void esIgual(char a[],char b[]){
    bool res=true;
    int la=0;
    int lb=0;
    for(int c=0;a[c]!='\0';c++){
        la++;
    }
    for(int c=0;b[c]!='\0';c++){
        lb++;
    }
    if(lb!=la){
        res = false;
    }
    else{
        for(int c=0;a[c]!='\0';c++){
            if(a[c]!=b[c]){
                res =false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta ¿Puedes reformularla?

Comment: las operaciones estan en binario y son:
-0
-1
-10
-11
-100
estan en la matriz operaciones[5][8] . 5 porque son 5 operaciones y 8 porque maximo pueden usarse 8 bits
ahora operacion que pido por consola esta declarada como char operacion[8]
y quiero poder pasarle al metodo esIgual() la operacion del usuario que pido con cin y una operacion especifica digamos la primera fila de operaciones 
¿Còmo lo hago?

Comment: Esa reformulación no ayuda.